# Modifying the TIFF's attribute table value with R

Tags: raster, r, attribute-table

I use `raster::raster("test.tiff", RAT = T)` to read the file with the format of TIFF.
The TIFF is derived from ArcGIS pro generating using `Feature to Raster -> raster -> tiff`.
ArcGIS TIFF's attribution table as below:

[image]

As you can see, the fields of `OID`, `Value`, `Count` are not allowed to edit in ArcGIS Pro. But I really need to make `Value <- Name`. Thus, though ArcGIS Pro doesn't allow I to modify `Value` field, I could use other platform like Python or R to edit the value , and finally I resave the modified data to the TIFF But I don't know how to resave the TIFF. And I learned another way as below:

```
db = read.dbf('test.tif.vat.dbf')
db$Value = factor(db$Name)
write.dbf(db,'test.tif.vat.dbf')
```

Even though I can save without any warning, but finally , when I open the TIFF in ArcGIS Pro , there's any change in attribution table .

The reason that I want to modify the value of attribute

[image]

Can you tell me what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347311/rat-and-cell-values-in-rs-raster-objects/347321#347321) may help with working with raster attribute tables (RAT) in R. The key is in working with `levels`. If you have an associated attribute table you can access it using `levels(x)[[1]]` or for a specific attribute (eg., colors column for plotting) `levels(x)[[1]]$color`. So, if you want to modify the raster attributes you could coerce it to a data.frame, operate on it, put it back into the correct slot, and then write out the raster. Something along the lines of:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(extent(571823, 616763, 4423540, 4453690), resolution=100)
  r[] <- sample(c(1:4), ncell(r), replace = TRUE) 
    r <- ratify(r)
```

Here we modify the attribute table

```
( r.df <- levels(r)[[1]] )
  ( r.df <- data.frame(r.df, y=runif(nrow(r.df))) )
```

Now, put the modified data.frame back into the attribute slot. Please note that first column must be `ID` with values that correspond with the values in the raster. Then you can write out the raster using `raster::writeRaster`

```
levels(r) <- r.df
  levels(r)
```

Comment: It sounds you are right. And thank you . But it's sitll abstract for me because I am a beginner in raster package. I wish someone could help me guide me in the first case. Really thank you .
Example:
I have a 'reg21.tiff'. And I access it with ArcGIS. And I found its VALUEis as below:
VALUE
100
300
400
500
600
700

I want to modify its VALUE:
VALUE
1
3
4
5
6
7
.So can you help me How to use Raster to modify. If you are convenient, please show your code. Thank you in advance.
This is the reg21.tif
Link：https://pan.baidu.com/s/1YGjCBgKaRsKPZqiTzvIJzg 
extract code：m8iu

Comment: Ah, also , I need to rewrite new name as 'reg.tif'.  If you can do it, please show the whole code.  Hope you have a good time. Thank you.